# How to realize numpy.allclose in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

In numpy, there is an [`allclose` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)
which compares two tensors per element. The inputs are mainly two tensors and thresholds.

If I do it in Fortran, if I use arrays `A` and `B` as the arguments of the subroutines, I need to declare the dimensions of the arrays in the subroutine first, before doing subsequent operations. This would require me to put the dimensions of arrays into the argument. And complicates the input. Is there any simpler way to realize something like `allclose` in Fortran?

Comment: Firstly the inputs are arrays, not tensors. Arrays are one way to represent tensors, but that does not mean they *are* tensors.

Comment: Secondly is `If( All( Abs( A - B ) < tol ) ) Then ...` acceptable?

Comment: Thanks. For the first, I guess tensor means some element in $V \otimes V \cdots V^* \otimes V^*$, if one picks up a basis, the components will be arrays(?). For the second, yes, accetable. I checked the intrinsic `All` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ALL.html, is there a way to specify the thresold?

Comment: Not sure I understand - you specify a tolerance by giving `tol` a value. This seems to obvious, is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry  I overlooked the  `tol` in your second reply. I will try.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will write my test as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments from Ian Bush. The following code works.

```
Program compare_array_test
  
    real :: A(2,2), B(2,2), E(2,2,2), F(2,2,2)
    complex :: C(2,2), D(2,2)
    real :: tol
  
    A = 1.0
    B = 1.0
    A(1,1) = 1.01
  
    tol = 0.0001
  
    If( All( Abs( A - B ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if 
    
    tol = 0.1
  
    If( All( Abs( A - B ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if      
  
    C = (1.0, 1.0)
    D = (1.0, 1.0)
    C(1,1) = (1.01, 1.00)
  
    tol = 0.0001
  
  
    If( All( cabs( C - D ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if 
    
    tol = 0.1
  
    If( All( cabs( C - D ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if     


    E = 1.0
    F = 1.0
    E(1,1,1) = 1.01
  
    tol = 0.0001
  
    If( All( Abs( E - F ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if 
    
    tol = 0.1
  
    If( All( Abs( E - F ) < tol ) ) Then
      write (*,*) 'within the threshold' 
    else
      write (*,*) 'above the threshold'      
    end if     

end program
```

Comment: There's no need to use cabs for complex numbers, and hasn't been since 1977. Just use Abs.

Comment: Thanks. I found in https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/a-to-b/abs.html  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnc8/index.html , `gfortran` page provides an example code but not mathematical definition https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ABS.html

Comment: Honestly - get a decent book. `Abs` of a complex number returns its modulus. The specific names referred to on the Intel page shouldn't have been used in decades (except in  some very unusual circumstances) - use the generic version.

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendation for book(s)? I learned from a non-English Fortran 90 book a long time ago and the book is no longer with me, not in https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Books